there exists a polynomial time algorithm for graph non-isomorphism
I am following the book, Theory of Computational Complexity, 2nd Edition Ding-Zhu Du, Ker-I Ko.
I am copying following text from the book,
Recently an algorithm was found that solves the isomorphism problem between $\text{GI}$ graphs in time $2^{O(\log^c(n))}$ for permanent certain $1 < c.$
Reminder:

the language $\text{GI} = \{\langle _1, _2 \rangle∶ _1 \text{ is isomorphic to } _2\}$
the language $\text{GNI} = \{\langle _1, _2 \rangle∶ _1 \text{ is NOT isomorphic to } _2\}$

As for, the graphs in the above context are not directed.Assume in addition that we know that this is the optimal complexity of the problem (i.e., best algorithm).
My question is: how to prove or refute that there exists a polynomial time algorithm for $\text{GNI}$?
My progress:
GI is in NP. Since, Given $(G_1, G_2)$ along with the bijection $φ$ as a certificate to the poly time deterministic verifier
$M$. It can easily verify whether G1 and G2 are isomorphic or not.GNI is the complement of GI. Thus, $\text{GNI} ∈ \text{co-NP}$. Since we could solve all $\text{co-NP}$ problems in polynomial time.Therefore I conclude that there exists a polynomial time algorithm for $\text{GNI}$.
Would anyone check my argument is right track or not?

It's open whether we can solve all co-NP problems in polynomial time. (Probably we cannot.)

Do you mean "$2^{O(\log^c(n))}$ for an absolute constant $c>1$", rather than a "permanent certain"? (I have another formatting nitpick as well: the title of the book is not code in a programming language, so it should not be in a code block. Notably, this affects how some screen readers will interpret it!)

@MishaLavrov more conveniently it is for some constant $c > 1.$

@CarlSchildkraut would look up my updated question please.

crosspost: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/170539/polynomial-time-algorithm-for-3sat-using-graph-isomorphism

@spaceisdarkgreen it's not the same question, both are different question.

@Beduin Ok, well, in either case, the lower bound implies GI is not in P, which implies the answer.

@spaceisdarkgreen you mean to say, GI is not in P, but GI is in NP. So you mean to say, there exists a non deterministic polynomial time algorithm for GNI
.

@Beduin GI is not in P (under these assumptions), so GNI (the complement of GI) is not in P. GI being in NP is relevant for the other one.

@spaceisdarkgreen you mean GI is NP -complete? Am I correct?

@Beduin No, GI is (probably) not NP complete. All that's relevant to the other question is that it's NP. 3SAT is NP complete though... that's relevant. (And whether GI is NP or not is irrelevant to this question... all that matters is it's not in $P$, so GNI is not in $P$.)

@spaceisdarkgreen GNI is not in P
and GNI is in coNP, from these what can we conclude? There is no polynomial algorithm for GNI. Am I correct?

From the point of view of the existence of algorithms to solve the problem, there is absolutely no reason to distinguish GI from GNI. The following are all true:

There is a $2^{O((\log n)^c)}$ algorithm for GI, so there is also a $2^{O((\log n)^c)}$ algorithm for GNI.
If we assume that the fastest algorithm for GI is $2^{\Omega((\log n)^c)}$, then the fastest algorithm for GNI is also $2^{\Omega((\log n)^c)}$.
If we can find a polynomial-time algorithm for GNI, then we can find a polynomial-time algorithm for GI.

The justification is simple: if you take an algorithm for GI, and reverse its output for all pairs of graphs (changing "accept" to "reject" and vice versa), then you get an algorithm for GNI. If you take an algorithm for GNI, and reverse its output for all pairs of graphs, then you get an algorithm for GI.
Therefore the question is equivalent to asking: if the fastest algorithm for one of these problems is $2^{\Omega((\log n)^c)}$, is there a polynomial-time algorithm? And the answer is: no, because $2^{\Omega((\log n)^c)}$ is worse than polynomial.

Why, then, do we bother distinguishing GI from GNI in any context?
This is only relevant for complexity classes like NP and co-NP. These complexity classes are not defined by how fast the fastest algorithm for solving a problem is. I will not go through the details of their definitions in this answer, but the important point is that

a problem is in NP if there is a polynomial-time verifier of "proofs" that an input is an element of the language;
a problem is in co-NP if there is a polynomial-time verifier of "proofs" that an input is not an element of the language.

This introduces an asymmetry between "accept" or "reject" decisions, and so the statements "GI is in NP" and "GNI is in NP" are no longer equivalent.
Rather, the reversing-the-output trick is going to tell us that "GI is in NP" is equivalent to "GNI is in co-NP", and "GI is in co-NP" is equivalent to "GNI is in NP". However, neither of these is relevant to the question at hand.
